# best practice for data manipulation + validation

Tags: backbone.js

I need to store some data in my `model` which are dates+times in a Unix standard representation (ms from 1970), but what I do is call `set` by passing a string like "Tue Jul 30 2013 12:25:43 GMT+0200 (CEST)". The string is what I can obtain from my `view` and I don't really want to convert it in my view, because I think it's a `model`'s duty to do it. By this way the functionalities are well organized and neat. So:

I put this in my model:

```
initialize: function() {
    var self= this;

    //conversion of the string date  into milliseconds
    this.on("change:start_time", function(model, start_time) {
        if(start_time !== null){
            var data= new Date(start_time);
            self.attributes.start_time= data.valueOf();
        }
    });
 ...
```

and it works like a charm. The problems is when you want to set the `start_time` property and validate it at the same time from one of my `view`s:

```
this.model.set({
    start_time: startDatePicker.getLocalDate()
}, {validate : true});
```

what's the matter here? **Validation is performed before the event handler I set in the initialization is triggered**. I found a workaround: moving the conversion into a new function and call it both in the .on and in the validation. But I think something neater is possible. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `start_time` will be validated before a `change` event is fired. Also, it is discouraged to set `model.attributes` directly, instead use `set` and pass `{silent:true}` if you don't want a `change` event fired.

I suggest one of the following methods and get rid of your event handler.

Do the conversion before calling set:

```
var dt = new Date(startDatePicker.getLocalDate()).valueOf();
this.model.set({
   start_time: dt
 }, {validate : true});
```

If you insist that your model does the conversion, another option is over-riding the `set` method in your model:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  set:function(key,val,options) {
    var attrs;

    // from Backbone source
    if (typeof key === 'object') {
      attrs = key;
      options = val;
    } else {
      (attrs = {})[key] = val;
    }

    if (attrs['start_time'])
      attrs['start_time'] = new Date(attrs['start_name']).valueOf();

    Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call(this,attrs,options);
 }
 // your existing code 
});
```

Personally, I would choose the first method.

Comment: Yes, I had already thought about the first method you mentioned, but I personally think that you're scattering functionalities that should be stuck into the model class, not in the view ones.

Comment: The second one is really cool and it permits me to discover what's under the bonnet of backbone little by little! Thanks!